# Change character value RegEx in java

Tags: java, regex, character, regular-language

I need to use '+' character instead of '|' character in regular expression in java. So , if i write something like 0+1 regular expresion 0 "or" 1 input should be accepted. '+' sign should references "OR" operation instead of '|'. How can i do this?

Comment: You will probably have to write your own regex engine. Why don't you tell us what your problem is *completely*

Comment: I think my own regex work quitely. If i use '|' , it work but '+' means one or more character of this value. I have to change '|' to '+'

Comment: You can write a regex class that replaces these special characters for you, then invokes the builtin regex.
Can you give us more context? I.e. why is it important to do so? What are the edge cases?

Comment: What about situations where `+` has a different meaning, e. g. if it's escaped, or in a character class, or part of a possessive quantifier? It's not as simple as just replacing all `+` signs with `|`.

Comment: That's right, Tim. This is why we need more context to see what kind of workarounds we can get away with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you will need to create your own automata for regex, what is way to complex... or you just need to do a replace into your string before you call the mathes regex method.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String regex = "0+1".replaceAll("\\+", "|");
    System.out.println("0".matches(regex));
}
```

but i had to say that is a door for a lot of bugs.

Comment: I solved problem with something like                                                         String regex = regex.replaceAll("\\+", "|");